# httpclient PostAsync Chinese encoding GBK Charset

Tags: dotnet-httpclient

```
  httpclient hc=new httpclient();
  var postcontent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string> {
                            {"subject",""},
                            {"message",content}

                        });

                    var post = await hc.PostAsync(postURI, postcontent);
```

FormUrlEncodedContent encoding for UTF-8

content is Chinese

how can i do for Encoding.GBK

httpclient PostAsync Chinese encoding GBK

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe what you are trying to do is possible.  From the specification of `application/www-form-urlencoded` [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hoehrmann-urlencoded-01#page-8) it says,

> Note: The media type does not have a 'charset' parameter, it
> is incorrect specify one and to associate any significance to
> it if specified. The character encoding is always UTF-8. The
> Unicode encoding form signature is not supported; a leading
> U+FEFF character will be considered part of a .

Apparently this is one difference between `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `application/www-form-urlencoded`.  The latter didn't explicitly force UTF-8 but apparently it was a best practice.  It looks like you might have to write your own HttpContent class and do the serialization yourself.